# Cannot parametrize version in Gradle plugins block

Tags: gradle

In Gradle when I declare plugin with hardcoded version it works well:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
}
```

However, if I try to parametrize it then I get exception.

Contents of `gradle.properties`:

```
springBootVersion=2.1.4.RELEASE
```

Contents of `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "$springBootVersion"
}
```

Why the following exception is happening?

```
Cause: startup failed:
build file 'build.gradle': 10: argument list must be exactly 1 literal non empty string

See https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block for information on the plugins {} block

 @ line 10, column 5.
       id 'org.springframework.boot' version "$springBootVersion"
       ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are facing is a [documented limitation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.3.1/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations) of the `plugins` block. You cannot use parameterization in it.

What's possible is to delegate the configuration of the version of the plugin to the `settings.gradle`.

In `gradle.properties`:

```
springBootVersion=2.1.4.RELEASE
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
// Must be the first statement of settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "org.springframework.boot") {
                useModule("org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:${springBootVersion}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parametrize the version by defying a variable in the project level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.PLUGIN_VERSION = 'VERSION'
}
```

And then use it in the app level `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'PLUGIN_NAME' version "$PLUGIN_VERSION"
}
```